# dashed dividers in vertical ListView (Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, divider, dotted-line

I went through all of the dashed divider topics alrady, but somehow my issue persists:

I have a vertical LinearLayout and want to display dashed dividers between each item in the LinearLayout. I use the following shape, but still get a straight line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="line">

    <stroke
        android:color="#7b7b75"
        android:dashGap="2dp"
        android:dashWidth="1dp"
    />

    <size android:height="1dp"/>



</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
drawable/dotted.xml:

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#C7B299"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px" />
</shape>
```

view.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted" />
```

Comment: then change the height to 1 dp.

Comment: the dashed line shows up in eclipse, but on my phone it's a straight line again